# Playing Audio on Raspberry Pi as root does not work

Tags: python, audio

I have tried simpleaudo, pydub, sounddevice with sound file, and a few others and they work as non-root user, but not as a root user.  I found a few documents that said the default device is different for root, which seems to be the case.  I came up with this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sounddevice as sd
import soundfile as sf

filename = '/home/jepalmer/PY/Lightning.wav'
sd.default.device = [2, None]
print(sd.query_devices())

data, fs = sf.read(filename, dtype='float32')
sd.play(data, fs)
status = sd.wait()
```

When run as myself I get this output:

```
me@raspberrypi2:~/PY $ just_audio3.py
  0 sysdefault, ALSA (0 in, 128 out)
  1 lavrate, ALSA (0 in, 128 out)
> 2 samplerate, ALSA (0 in, 128 out)
  3 speexrate, ALSA (0 in, 128 out)
  4 pulse, ALSA (32 in, 32 out)
  5 upmix, ALSA (0 in, 8 out)
  6 vdownmix, ALSA (0 in, 6 out)
  7 dmix, ALSA (0 in, 2 out)
< 8 default, ALSA (32 in, 32 out)
```

And the audio plays fine, but as root I get this:

```
me@raspberrypi2:~/PY $ sudo ./just_audio3.py
  0 sysdefault, ALSA (0 in, 128 out)
  1 lavrate, ALSA (0 in, 128 out)
> 2 samplerate, ALSA (0 in, 128 out)
  3 speexrate, ALSA (0 in, 128 out)
  4 upmix, ALSA (0 in, 8 out)
  5 vdownmix, ALSA (0 in, 6 out)
< 6 default, ALSA (0 in, 128 out)
  7 dmix, ALSA (0 in, 2 out)
```

Which I have tried all the options and it doesn't work as root.  What am I missing?  There has to be a way of doing this via software and having to resort to a hardware HDMI audio splitter.